# Chrome tab hang on window resize in React app wrapping non-react module -- "disconnected port object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- Windows 10 Google
- Chrome 92.0.4515.107
- React 17 'create-react-app'
- Hosting a non-react 'app' as a JS library

**Summary**: 'Wrapping' non-react editing/drawing library/app in react. Lib sourced in  tags, not import. Reference via .window. Loads fine and I can use it until I 'hide' it's parent  and then resize the window --> chrome tab hangs, totally unresponsive. Chrome verbose logging shows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined", source: chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopl...
Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object at lOne (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofa....
```

**Everything:** This wrapped 'app' is a visual editor that I'm trying to reuse. It's not react, and it's not 'importable' without a lot of refactoring: I source it in via `<script>` tags in index.html. In the react code, in a wrapper component, I render a `<div>` and then add the wrapped application into that div -- this is how the app expects to be loaded. The hosting wrapper references the app via a generic JS (singleton) object which uses 'window.' to reference the wrapped app object:

```js
// EditorWrapper.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Editor from './Editor';

export default class EditorWrapper extends Component {
  editor = null;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
  }

  // Should happen only once for lifetime of app (?)
  componentDidMount() {
    this.editor = Editor.getInstance();
    this.editor.loadEditor();
  }

  handleSave() {
    this.props.updateParent(this.editor.getData());
  }
  
  render() {
    if (this.editor !== null)
      this.editor.setData(props.getParentData());

    return (
      // Editor gets 'loaded' into this div in the Editor obj
      <div id="editor_div" style={{ display: this.props.show ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.handleSave()}>Save</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// Editor.js
export default class Editor {
  loaded = false;
  editor = null;
  static theInstance = null;

  constructor() {
    this.setEditor = null;
    this._scilReadyCallback = this._scilReadyCallback.bind(this);
  }

  // singleton
  static getInstance() {
    if (this.theInstance === null)
      this.theInstance = new EditorLoader();
    return this.theInstance;
  }

  getData() {
    return this.editor.app.getData();
  }

  setData(data) {
    this.editor.app.setData(data);
  }

  loadEditor = () => {
    if (!this.loaded) {
      this.loaded = true;
      window.scil.ready(this._scilReadyCallback);
    }
  }

  _scilReadyCallback() {
    window._editorPlugin.init("editor_div");  // add to DOM
    this.editor = window._editor;
  }
}
```

The wrapped editor is a visual editor where you can add various graphical objects and manipulate them. It relies on [JS Draw Lite](https://www.scilligence.com/web/jsdraw-lite/) underneath. It is heavy-weight to load (makes a bunch of network requests), so I just leave the whole thing in the DOM and show/hide the parent `<div>` as needed.

Should this even work? Or am I 'breaking react' by doing this? Is there a better way to encapsulate this external code?

Steps to reproduce bug:

- Run the main app: the wrapped editor app loads hidden at app start
- Click a button to reveal the editor (show the div)
- Do some drawing in the editor

  - **If I do no drawing, only 'view and hide' the editor, bug does not trigger.**
- Click a button to save data/hide the editor
- **Manually resize the Chrome window**  (click the window edge and drag)

Bug:

- Chrome tab freezes/hangs: nothing on the page is responsive in any way
- Chrome CPU usage jumps from ~10% to ~30% and stays there until the tab is closed
- I am able to close the tab without having to close the entire browser window: once I click the 'x' on the tab it doesn't close, but a second click closes it.
- Once tab closes, CPU drops back down

I've enabled verbose logging in Chrome (--enable-logging --v=1), and I get the following printing out every second or so once the hang starts:

```
[16484:16444:0802/173052.471:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) undefined", source: chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/main.html (0)
[16484:16444:0802/173052.487:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error in event handler: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at lOne (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/background.js:139:9)", source: chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/_generated_background_page.html (0)
```

How else to debug this? Chrome dev-tools freezes along with anything else, so I can't profile to see what might be 'triggering' the freeze. I've started debugging into the editor code, but it's a pretty big black hole.

Things continue to work fine until I resize the Chrome window: I can show/hide the editor, work in the editor, communicate between editor and wrapper: all fine until I resize the window. Resizing must 'redraw' the window, and the CPU jump/hang suggests some kind of infinite loop on a timer...?? Ngaaah.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I:

- created a simple app that use only the index.html to load the editor along with some simple jQuery in the same to show and hide the editor with buttons. No react at all.
- I was able to reproduce the issue even with this simple app
- So, I started looking for other ways to show/hide the editor. I stumbled on a way to use the 'visibility' CSS attribute instead of the 'display' attribute. If you use visibility with a `flex` container, and then use the 'visible' and 'collapse' values to show and hide, the bug disappears.
- Then, I just implemented this on top of the original code, keeping the editor's parent div in index.html with some very minor tweaks to use the JQuery (vs React) for show and hide

Editor.js

```
  ...
  showEditor() {
    window.$("#editor").css("visibility", "visible");
  }

  hideEditor() {
    window.$("#editor").css("visibility", "collapse");
  }
  ...
```